# How to order grouped columns in an ActiveRecord Postgres query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to build a sidebar for a blog that contains pretty standard archive information like:

August 2013: 3 posts

July 2013: 5 posts

June 2013: 4 posts

...etc

**What ActiveRecord query will provide this information (`month`, `year`, `count`) sorted reverse-chronologically?**

The Post model is very simple -- `title`, `body`, `created_at`, `modified_at` columns.  I'm trying to write the ActiveRecord/Postgres query that gives me the count of posts grouped by month and year (as listed above).  The following query does just that, successfully:

`Post.select('count(*) as count','extract(year from created_at) as year', 'extract(month from created_at) as month').group('year','month')`

But I want to explicitly sort the columns reverse chronologically (so August 2013 is above July 2013 in the listing) and that's where everything goes haywire.  I tried the following query unsuccessfully, just to get started:

`Post.select('count(*) as count','extract(year from created_at) as year', 'extract(month from created_at) as month').group('year','month').order(:year => :desc)`

It produces the following SQL:

`SELECT count(*) as count, extract(year from created_at) as year, extract(month from created_at) as month FROM "posts" GROUP BY year, month ORDER BY "posts"."year" DESC`

And the following error:

`PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column posts.year does not exist`

The query actually runs if I order by count using `.order(:count => :desc)` but it doesn't seem to actually be ordering in the way I would have expected (switching to `:asc` does nothing different).

I've scoured SO and google but to no avail.  I've also tried sorting by `created_at` but it throws a `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "posts.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` error.  Ideally, I'd run a simple `Post.order(:created_at => :desc)`, THEN run the grouping queries on that nicely ordered result, but I don't know how.

Very lost... how do I retrieve the posts with `year` and `month` and `count` columns but order the resulting groups reverse chronologically?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does `.order('year desc')` work? Which version of Rails is this? My 3.2 doesn't like your `select` or `order` calls at all.

Comment: @mu is too short, using Rails 4.0.0, Ruby 2.0.0-p247

Comment: That explains my problems testing things out, I don't have a Rails4 set up handy. I'm guessing that `.order('year desc')` will work as AR should pass the string through to the SQL unmolested (unlike when you use a Hash where AR thinks it knows what it is doing but doesn't really).

Answer (score 1):

Not all databases allow you to reference a derived column name in a `GROUP` or `ORDER` clause. I don't know PostgreSQL myself, but perhaps it supports relative column references.  Try this:

```
SELECT count(*) as count
     , extract(year from created_at) as year
     , extract(month from created_at) as month 
FROM "posts" 
GROUP BY 2, 3 
ORDER BY 2 DESC, 3 DESC
```

If that doesn't work, this should:

```
SELECT count(*) as count
     , extract(year from created_at) as year
     , extract(month from created_at) as month 
FROM "posts" 
GROUP BY extract(year from created_at), extract(month from created_at)
ORDER BY extract(year from created_at) DESC, extract(month from created_at) DESC
```